# Android Tablet as Pi monitor without WiFi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3, usb, monitoring

Is it possible to display Raspberry Pi through android tablet without WiFi? 
I wanted to do that so I can avoid the constrains over the the Pi and the Tablet Wifi. In addition to that I wanted easy setup so you can display the Pi over the Tablet with a single click if you moved to different place where it has a different WiFi. Also it would be easier for a user with little knowledge of networking and vnc to use the Pi without  going through a setup. (tethering a Wifi _ connect the pi through ssh _ run vnc client and connect to the Pi address).

So I was thinking if it is possible to Bluetooth pair the Pi and the Tablet and the Pi VNC server linked to Bluetooth and the VNC client on the tablet read the server from Bluetooth.

Or to direct the the VNC server towards a USB port and the Tablet reads the VNC from the USB.

Or to use a capture card takes feed from the Pi HDMI out put and transfer it into data throught USB. And to have application on the tablet that reads that feed from the capture card.

Or to program the Pi as capture card so it transmit it display through USB.

Comment: You might be able to do the bluetooth thing if your phone can share internet that way -- presuming the Pi 3 can pair as a slave (I haven't used for anything so I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

I have used an approach to access a personal Wiki running on the Pi from other computers that might work for what you want to do.

This approach also allows me to remote into the Pi from a tablet, basically using the tablet as the monitor of the headless Pi.

It uses WiFi to connect but differently, you don't need to join the local WiFi network, or know the IP address of the Pi.  With this, the Pi acts as a server, and from the tablet you select the Pi's WiFi network and would always to connect the same way no matter where you are, even where there is no regular WiFi.

First, enable the VNC Server available on the Pi.

Second, you need to setup the Pi to be an Access Point (AP). [Here is a great step by step tutorial](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/).

Then, you can connect from your tablet to the Pi's network, and use a VNC Client to remote into it, effectively using the table as the Pi's monitor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does RPi need an ethernet connection too to act as WiFi AP? I don't need any internet connection, but I was asking myself if RPi could act as AP without an internet connection.

Comment: just tested, not need ethernet connection. Works great!